# @font-face not showing bold version of font despite it declaration - why?

Tags: html, css, fonts

I have created a small sandbox page, and while the CSS does work, the font-face is a problem for locally-hosted Open Sans downloaded from Google Fonts.

I've hosted the fonts locally so this test page is self-contained for now.

```css
body {
 font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
}
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5 {
 font-family:"Open Sans", Helvetica, Arial,sans-serif;
 font-weight:400;
 font-style:normal;
 line-height:1.4em;
 color:#333;
 margin:0 0 15px 0;
}
h1 {
 font-size:22px;
}
h2 {
 font-size:20px;
}
h3 {
 font-size:18px;
}
h4 {
 font-size:16px;
}
h5 {
 font-size:14px;
}
p {
 font-family:"Open Sans", Helvetica, Arial,sans-serif;
 font-weight:400;
 font-style:normal;
 font-size:14px;
 line-height:1.2em;
 color:#333;
 margin:0 0 15px 0
}
a {
text-decoration: none;
}
b {
font-family: Open Sans, sans-serif;
font-weight: 700;
}
#header {
  background: #01b14c;
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.15);
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 6px 0;
}
.fal.fa-phone::before {
  content: "\ea39";
}
.footer {
  padding: 60px 0;
  background: #000;
  color: #FFF;
}
#cloned-hometext {
width: 470px;
}

.about-text {
font-size: 13px;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    src: local('Open Sans Regular'), local('OpenSans-Regular'),
    url('fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf'); 
    font-display: swap;   
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    src:
    url('fonts/OpenSans-Bold.ttf');
    font-weight: 700;
    font-display: swap;
    font-style: bold;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    src: local('Open Sans ExtraBold'), local('OpenSans-ExtraBold'),
    url('fonts/OpenSans-ExtraBold.ttf');
    font-weight: 900;
    font-display: swap;
    font-style: bold;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Test page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<header id="header">
<h1>A TEST</h1>
</header>
<div id="cloned-hometext" class="about-text">
  <h1>TEST</h1>
<p>This is a test</p>
<h3>This works</h3>
<b>It's got to work</b>
</div>
<footer class="footer">
Content to come
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Despite having the OpenSans-Bold font in fonts folder of styles where style.css resides the document only shows Open Sans or a faux-bold.

These are all the fonts in the directory:

OpenSans-Bold.ttf

OpenSans-ExtraBold.ttf

OpenSans-Medium.ttf

OpenSans-Regular.ttf

OpenSans-SemiBold.ttf

However, the bold font is not showing even when I declare   in HTML.

How can I resolve this in the CSS I have?

Note in the code above, that's the content of style.css ; it's not inline.

Comment: works fine in the snippet you provided

Comment: @tacoshy: It's showing the default font, not OpenSans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add format('truetype') to your @font-face declaration. Also if it doesn't work, then move the @font-face declarations to the top of CSS.

Also if Open Sans is your default font, then apply it to the body and you don't have to specify font-family to all your elements over and over, like you're doing now.

Also are you sure about the path to font files, looks like it might need some dots and slashes upfront.

Answer (score 0):

Check your path url to your font file, if it was in the same path change url path to "url('./fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf')"